# Prove that $2^n$ is not a polynomial in an algebraic way.

Tags: abstract-algebra

There is no polynomial $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $P(n) = 2^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I already know the analysis way to prove this using $\lim$, derivations or Taylor series.

But this is an algebra assignment with the following hint: Consider the polynomial $P(X+ 1)−2P(X)$. I have already written this polynomial together as $Q[X]=\sum_{i=0}^na_i((X+1)^i-2X^i)$ but I have got no clue what this polynomial is supposed to tell me. I'd be thankful for further hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know why @Lord Shark the Unknown deleted his answer, since it is essentially correct. If $P$ has degree $n$, so does $Q(x)=P(x+1)-2P(x)$ and its leading term is $-ax^n$ where $a$ is the leading coefficient of $P$. But, it has infinitely many zeroes since $P(m+1)=2P(m)$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus it must be identically zero, a contradiction.